# Source Attachment does not contain the source for the file ThreadPoolExecutor.class

Tags: android, threadpoolexecutor

I am working on an android project which uses the `webservice` I have created. It was working fine few minutes earlier but suddenly it started to give below error.
**the source attachment does not contain the source for the file threadpoolexecutor.class**

**Logcat error is :**

```
07-10 11:30:22.844: E/AndroidRuntime(1707): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-10 11:30:22.844: E/AndroidRuntime(1707): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-10 11:30:22.844: E/AndroidRuntime(1707):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
07-10 11:30:22.844: E/AndroidRuntime(1707):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
07-10 11:30:22.844: E/AndroidRuntime(1707):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
07-10 11:30:22.844: E/AndroidRuntime(1707):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
07-10 11:30:22.844: E/AndroidRuntime(1707):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-10 11:30:22.844: E/AndroidRuntime(1707):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-10 11:30:22.844: E/AndroidRuntime(1707):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-10 11:30:22.844: E/AndroidRuntime(1707):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-10 11:30:22.844: E/AndroidRuntime(1707): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-10 11:30:22.844: E/AndroidRuntime(1707):     at com.example.backgroundTask.BackgroundTask.RegisterUser(BackgroundTask.java:125)
07-10 11:30:22.844: E/AndroidRuntime(1707):     at com.example.backgroundTask.BackgroundTask.doInBackground(BackgroundTask.java:65)
07-10 11:30:22.844: E/AndroidRuntime(1707):     at com.example.backgroundTask.BackgroundTask.doInBackground(BackgroundTask.java:1)
07-10 11:30:22.844: E/AndroidRuntime(1707):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-10 11:30:22.844: E/AndroidRuntime(1707):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
07-10 11:30:22.844: E/AndroidRuntime(1707):     ... 4 more
07-10 11:30:23.174: W/Trace(1707): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

Please tell me what may cause this error or let me know if more information required.
Thanks & Regards..
Sourabh

Comment: "Please tell me what may cause this error" -- the error is caused by you calling a method on `null` in line 125 of `BackgroundTask.java`, somewhere in an unfortunately-named `RegisterUser()` method.

Comment: I found it. I was checking the value and if everything if fine it will return null from the web service. and that null value I was trying to convert to string value and hence geting the above error.

Comment: Thanks for help commonsware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. I was checking the value and if everything if fine it will return null from the web service. and that null value I was trying to convert to string value and hence geting the above error.
Thanks  CommonsWare.