# NullPointerException by parsing JSON

Tags: php, android, json

I try to do this tutorial [Tuturial Part 5](http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/13193/android-mysql-php-json-part-5-developing-the-android-application/) and I got a NullPointerException in Regisert.java at the line with the code:

```
Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());
```

I am using WAMP server and I already save my php file under the directory www. that means my string variable URL ist

```
"http://10.0.2.2:80/www/login_tutorial/register.php"
```

. Hier ist my log.txt

```
07-13 19:56:20.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29385): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-13 19:56:20.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29385): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error    occured while executing doInBackground()
07-13 19:56:20.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29385):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
07-13 19:56:20.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29385):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
07-13 19:56:20.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29385):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
07-13 19:56:20.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29385):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
07-13 19:56:20.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29385):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-13 19:56:20.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29385):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
07-13 19:56:20.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29385):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-13 19:56:20.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29385):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-13 19:56:20.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29385):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-13 19:56:20.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29385): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-13 19:56:20.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29385):    at com.example.mysqltest.Register$CreateUser.doInBackground(Register.java:105)
07-13 19:56:20.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29385):    at com.example.mysqltest.Register$CreateUser.doInBackground(Register.java:1)
07-13 19:56:20.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29385):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
07-13 19:56:20.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29385):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-13 19:56:20.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29385):    ... 5 more
```

can somebody tell me why it doesn't work for me?!

thanks

I took the code from the link above but it's ok I'll post it here again.

```
public class Register extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private EditText user, pass;
private Button mRegister;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:80/www/login_tutorial/register.php";

private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    mRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
    mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    new CreateUser().execute();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     */
    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating user...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        int success;
        String username = user.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

            Log.d("request", "starting");

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                // full json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                // json success element
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("User created", json.toString());
                    finish();
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("Login Failure", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
        if (result != null) {
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

the methode for pasing JSON is here:

```
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params) {
    // Making HTTP Request
    try {
        // check for request method
        if (method == "POST") {
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHTTPClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } else if (method == "GET") {


            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer error", "Error converting result" + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return jObj;
}
```

why it gives me null as result for JSON?

Comment: Your variable json is null.  Post the code where you assign that variable (and any related code to get that data) if you need more help.

Comment: What is `json` . Pls post relevant code.

Comment: Please don't show logcat output as a screenshot image. Copy and paste it into a code block in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your jsonParser is not throwing an exception rather it is returning null for your request. Modify your jsonParser to always throw an exception in case of errors or add null handling for your json object here

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
if(json == null)
    return null;
```

Comment: yes, the json Parser give null as a result so I can just solve it with if clause. but do you know why it gives a null?

Comment: for that we will need to know the response from the network and what your jsonParser is doing with the response. Check the raw response of your http request before you give it to the parser. Mostly your requests ar enot returning valid responses from network, else your parser is doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

there must be something which have null value in your doInBackground() at line 105 and you are trying to access it, which is causing error. you can refer [Source Attachment does not contain the source for the file ThreadPoolExecutor.class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569789/source-attachment-does-not-contain-the-source-for-the-file-threadpoolexecutor-cl) for reference.

Hope this will help you.