# How to get object data from json file

Tags: android, json

I wrote this statement in order to get the media description and only the first 50 chars, but I got an exception, is there any logical error within this statement :

```
String description = ent.getJSONObject(i).
                getJSONObject("media$description").getString("$t").substring(0,49);
```

[image]

Stacktrace :

```
07-14 09:01:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(460): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-14 09:01:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(460): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-14 09:01:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at com.example.task_10_vedioserach.MainActivity$conn.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:156)
07-14 09:01:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at com.example.task_10_vedioserach.MainActivity$conn.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
07-14 09:01:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
07-14 09:01:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
07-14 09:01:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
07-14 09:01:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-14 09:01:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-14 09:01:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-14 09:01:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-14 09:01:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-14 09:01:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-14 09:01:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-14 09:01:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**All my code :**

package com.example.task_10_vedioserach;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView vediolist;
    ImageButton search;
    Button history;
    EditText title;
    /////////////////
    ArrayList<String > videoInfo; 
    ArrayAdapter< String > Listadapter ; 
    ProgressDialog progress ; 
    /////////////////

      String vedioName;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        vediolist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.vedioList);
        search = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.search);
        history = (Button) findViewById(R.id.history);
        title=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.vedioName);

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        videoInfo = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        Listadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,videoInfo);
        progress = new ProgressDialog(this); 
        progress.setMessage("Wait Loading .... "); 
        progress.setCancelable(false); 
        vediolist.setAdapter(new CustomList(MainActivity.this,videoInfo)); 





          search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                vedioName= title.getText().toString();
                new conn().execute("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q="+vedioName+"&v=2&alt=json"); 

            }
        });




    }




    class conn extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            progress.show(); 
            super.onPreExecute();

        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            String s = GetUrlBody(arg0[0]); 

            return s;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        try{



            JSONObject jo =(JSONObject) new JSONTokener(result).nextValue();


           JSONObject feed = jo.optJSONObject("feed");


           JSONArray ent = feed.optJSONArray("entry");



        for(int i = 0 ; i<ent.length() ; i++){

        String title = ent.getJSONObject(i).
                getJSONObject("title").getString("$t");
        String viewCount = ent.getJSONObject(i).
                getJSONObject("yt$statistics").getString("viewCount");

        String authorName=ent.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("author").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("name").getString("$t");

        String numDisLikes = ent.getJSONObject(i).
                getJSONObject("yt$rating").getString("numDislikes");

        String numLikes = ent.getJSONObject(i).
                getJSONObject("yt$rating").getString("numLikes");

        String description = ent.getJSONObject(i).
                getJSONObject("media$description").getString("$t").substring(0,49);



        videoInfo.add("Title"+title+"\n"+"By:"+authorName); 


        }



        Listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



        }catch(Exception exx) {


             Log.getStackTraceString(exx.getCause().getCause());

        }



            progress.dismiss(); 



            super.onPostExecute(result); 


        } 





        String GetUrlBody (String Url ){


            HttpClient cli = new DefaultHttpClient(); 


            HttpGet g = new HttpGet(Url); 


            try{



            HttpResponse res = cli.execute(g);


            if(res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){


                String s =EntityUtils.toString(res.getEntity(), HTTP.UTF_8); 


                return s; 

            }else {



                return "Not Found"; 


            }




            }catch(Exception exx){



                //Log.getStackTraceString(exx.getCause().getCause());


            }

            return null; 
        }





    }



}
```

Comment: According to your stack trace, you've got a NullPointerException, could you paste some of the related code as well?

Comment: One of those calls is returning null.  Most likely you don't have some field in your JSON that you expected to have there.  I'd break that statement up into multiple lines, figure out which is null, then either fix your data or refactor your code to use a default if it doesn't exist.

Comment: You are return `null` from `GetUrlBody` method. change it to `return "";` instead of `return null;` and give a try.

Answer (score 0):

You probably trying to access something which have null value on line 156 in onPostExecute() of conn class. Please check with [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569789/source-attachment-does-not-contain-the-source-for-the-file-threadpoolexecutor-cl).

Hope this will help you. or get back if any problem.

Regards..
Sourabh